# Amazon EC2: Nginx : Display the error log in different files for each App Server than all log in single file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have three rails projects running in single `EC2` instance in `CentOS`. I have a configuration for nginx as below in `/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`

```
....
log_format compression '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                   '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
                   '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';
..... 
server {
passenger_ruby /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/wrappers/ruby;
listen 80;
server_name my_app.com;

### Custom configs
passenger_enabled on;
root /home/ec2-user/www/my_app/current/public;
error_log /home/ec2-user/www/my_app/current/logs/error.log debug;
access_log /home/ec2-user/www/my_app/current/logs/access.log main;
rewrite_log on;
rails_env qa;
### Custom configs end


# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
root html;
}

server{
..}
server{.}
...
```

The above configuration didn't work for error log as expected.
I would like to have each individual app servers to have its own error log. Currently nginx log has the log for all the project/apps in the same log file. How can I do that.

Comment: Put individual `error_log`/`access_log` directive into each server block

Comment: Why you expect it will write in different files?